# How to get imageName and extension in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

Here I have one image (`xyz.abc.jpg`) I want this imageName and extension of this image. using below code I got image Extension, How to get imageName without extension like this( in this imagename has `.` also (`xyz.abc`)) ?

```
console.log(image);  // xyz.abc.jpg

// Using this I got Extension of image
var extension = image.split(".").pop();
console.log(extension); // jpg
```

Comment: Split string using . and take the last element from array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `image.join('.');` after the `pop` operation. `join` will take your string array as an input and convert it into a string by joining the elements of the string array with the string that you provided in the argument.

You can read more about [**`join()` here at MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

Give this a try:

```js
const imageName = `xyz.abc.jpg`;
const yourArray = imageName.split('.');
const imageExtension = yourArray.pop();
console.log(imageExtension);
console.log(yourArray.join('.'));
```

Comment: not full name of image without extension i want imagename

Comment: Yeah, you can try the above code by clicking on the Run Code Snippet button. That will give you the full name.